# How can i send and recv multiple files size in one socket c++?

Tags: sockets, c++11

i'm trying to develop a client/server application to share files..

1- Client send file size

2- Client send file data (name + content)

3- Server recv file size

4- Server recv file data (name + content)

I have my code that is working good for one file, and i'm asking how to edit it so i can send and receive size of multiple files ?

Can anyone help Plz !!!

Client code :

```
 cout << "[Client] Sending files name to the Server... " << endl ;
 int i=0;
 while(i<files_vector.size()){

                /************ Read & Send filename *************/


    string filename = files_vector[i].getFullNameFile();

    string test = filename+"&&";
    size_t nameLen = strlen(test.c_str());

     if(filename == "." || filename == "..")
        continue;

    string path_file = cf.pathSrcFiles+filename;

    std::ifstream infile(path_file, std::ifstream::binary);

    int32_t sizef = files_vector[i].getTaille();


        /*** Send file size to server ***/


        char fsize[256];
        sprintf(fsize, "%d", nameLen+sizef);

         if(send(sock, fsize, sizeof(fsize),0) < 0){
          perror("Error sending file size\n");

          exit(1);
        }
         /**** Send file data ****/

    char content_file[sizef];

    bzero(content_file, sizef);

    infile.read(content_file,sizef);

    string concat = test+string(content_file);
    char file[sizef];

    strcpy(file, concat.c_str());

        cout << "content : " << file << endl;
        cout << "size : " << nameLen+sizef << endl;

        if(send(sock, file, nameLen+sizef, 0) < 0)
        {
            cout << stderr << "ERROR: Failed to send file" << filename <<  " 
            (error no = " << errno << ")" << endl;
            break;
        }
        bzero(content_file, sizef);

        infile.close();

    cout << "Ok File " << filename << " from Client was Sent!\n" << endl;

  i++;
 }
```

Server code :

```
char csize[256];

int rc;

int32_t fsize;

/** Receive file size **/

if(rc = recv(sock, csize, 256, 0)) < 0){

    cout << "Error receiving file size" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

   csize[rc] = '\0';
   fsize = atoi(csize);

   int n = 0;
  int bytes_read = 0;

  char* file;
  file = new char[fsize];
  memset(file, 0, fsize);

  /** Receive file data **/

while((n = recv(sock, file+bytes_read, fsize-bytes_read, 0) > 0) && 
        (bytes_read < fsize)){


   cout << "content : " << file << endl;

   bytes_read += n;

    memset(file, 0, fsize);

   }
delete[] file;
```

Comment: Start with handling the return values of `send` and `recv` correctly. These functions may send or receive less than you requested. Read the documentation for these. Also send the file checksum at the end, so that the reader can validate the received data.

Comment: If there is anything else to read after reading filesize+data, that may be another file, don't you think?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks for your reply ^^ okey i will read the documentation, but what do you mean by the file checksum, i'm new in c++ and sockets so i'm sorry for these stupid quetions !!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks for your reply ^^ Yes it's surly another file, cuz i send files in for loop

Comment: The sender should just sum up all file bytes into a 32-bit integer and send that at the end. The receiver does the same calculation and compares with the received value.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Okey i get it, thank you !!

Comment: @NouhaNB Just make sure you sum into `unsigned` because it wraps, whereas `signed int` aka `int` doesn't.